# Can you use a string in the name of the control when setting its property?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list box with a lot of items, and each item is supposed to open a panel next to it. When an item is clicked, it brings it's respective panel to the front (the panels are all positioned in the same place).

I've tried using if statements to check the selected index, but this will result in 1000s of if statements which will end up being confusing.

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // gets item text
        string text = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        // brings panel to front
        panel**the text string goes here**.BringToFront();
    }
```

I'm trying to use a variable to get the text of the selected item and then use this variable in the name of the control (similarly to how you can use variables in strings), but it's not working for me. Is there an alternative way, or is this not possible?

Comment: `if (this.Controls.ContainsKey(panelName)) { Panel p = this.Controls[panelName] as Panel;} ` WinForms won't like thousands of controls.

Comment: You don't have an actual Panel for each Item in the list, right? Just the visible Items, maybe?

Comment: There is one panel per item all positioned in the same place, so when you click an item, it's respective panel is brought to the front.. Also Lars I don't understand your code or what panelName is.

Comment: So, you actually need just **one** Panel.

Comment: panelName =  `panel**the text string goes here**`

Comment: No, each panel has different control inside, related to the item in the list.

Comment: is text the name of the panel?

Comment: the text is only part of the name of the panel - every panel's name begins with "panel" and then ends with the text of the item it's related to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.7.2) for the control by name with `Controls.Find()`.  This will find it regardless of how deep it is nested inside other containers:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    string ctlName = "panel" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    Control ctl = this.Controls.Find(ctlName, true).FirstOrDefault();
    if (ctl != null)
    {
        ctl.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)`? (unless the user is able to deselect items)

Comment: @cd5ssmffan, it's possible to not have something selected; should always check for that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the controls collection of the Form Object

```
        var i = this.Controls.IndexOfKey("panel" + text);
        if(i != -1) this.Controls[i].BringToFront();
```

Comment: Seems `i` remains at -1 here, because it gave me an exception that Index -1 is out of range (when I removed the if statement)

Comment: If you Panel's are nested then yes it would return -1.  It assumed they were top level of the windows form.

Comment: No, they were in another panel. I should have made that clear before.

Answer (score -2):

The wright syntax is

panel1.Controls[(text)]

where text is your string variable